# Indexes and ranges in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def main():

    if (len(sys.argv) > 2) :
        P=list()
        f= open('Trace.txt' , 'w+')
        Seed = int(sys.argv[1])

        for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
            P[i-2] = int(sys.argv[i])
            for j in range(0, len(sys.argv)-1) :
                Probability=P[j]
                for Iteration in (K*j, K*(j+1)):
                    Instruction= generateInstruction(Seed, Probability)
                    f.write(Instruction)
                f.close()
    else:
        print('Params Error')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The idea is that I am passing some parameters through the command line. the first is seed and the rest I want to have them in a list that I am parsing later and doing treatments according to that parameter.
I keep receiving this error:

```
 P[i-2] = int(sys.argv[i])
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

what am I doing wrong

PS: K,  generateSegment() are defined in a previous part of the code.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is related to a `list` being indexed with an invalid index.

Specifically, the problem is that `P` is an empty list at the time is being called in that line so `P[0]` is indeed not accessible. Perhaps what you want is to actually add the element to the list, this can be achieved, for example, by replacing:

```
P[i-2] = int(sys.argv[i])
```

with:

```
P.append(int(sys.argv[i]))
```

Note also that argument parsing is typically achieved way more efficiently in Python by using the standard module [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), rather than parsing `sys.argv` manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be referencing a list item that does not exist.

I haven't used Python in quite a while but I'm pretty sure that if you want to add a value to the end of a list you can use `someList.append(foo)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are assigning a value to an index which does not yet exist.
You need to replace

```
P[i-2] = int(sys.argv[I])
```

with

```
P.append(int(sys.argv[i]))
```

Furthermore, `len(sys.argv)` will return the number of items in `sys.argv` however indexing starts at 0 so you need to change:

```
for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)):
```

with

```
for i in range(2, len(sys.argv)-1):
```

As you will run into a `list index out of range` error otherwise